# Efficient splitting long List in a set number of sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that should take a list of arguments and distribute it to a set number of threads for them to process it. But I have not yet found a quick and easy to implement way to split the arguments into smaller sub lists not of a set length but rather a predetermined number.
I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks), but the answers describe splitting into lists of a set length if I am not mistaken.
The function I want to implement this takes a list as parameter and has access to the current number of threads

I tried a method of splitting into list of set length where I just used `len(list) / nr_of_threads`, but I don't know how to efficiently handle cases where there might be to many / not enough sublists for every thread

My Question (tl;dr):
**Is there a very fast and efficient way of splitting a list into a set number of sub lists of about equal length?**

Comment: After splitting into smaller chunks, you should initailize a queue and after then you should pass element to func and pop that element from queue for each of your new thread.

Comment: I could try that, but then I probably want as small of a chunk size as possible (to equalize the amount of data per thread). Doesn't that mean quite a bit of overhead, since I have to repeatedly call the function with new data?

Comment: There is no other way to optimize it. You have to give each chunk to new thread. It's a thread not an another process. That means your variable isn't copied. Therefore, the complexity and memory usage is the same

Comment: I just used a shared list for all the threads, it works fine. Thank you anyways!